# GAE Standard Php, Linux development server error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

Using the Google Cloud SDK, as opposed to the App Launcher that is being phased out, I'm trying to setup the development Php environment on a Linux host. I've got the recommended Php version installed and here are the results of attempting to start a server.

```
INFO     2017-09-24 02:44:31,139 devappserver2.py:115] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2017-09-24 02:44:31,305 api_server.py:299] Starting API server at: http://localhost:42195
INFO     2017-09-24 02:44:31,408 dispatcher.py:224] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2017-09-24 02:44:31,410 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2017-09-24 02:44:32,434 module.py:1588] 
INFO     2017-09-24 02:44:33,412 shutdown.py:45] Shutting down.
INFO     2017-09-24 02:44:33,413 api_server.py:940] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2017-09-24 02:44:33,413 api_server.py:943] Saving search indexes
```

Comment: I am getting the same error when running dev_appserver.py app.yaml on a Raspbian Stretch installation

Comment: @abel, you should have provided a reproducible sample for someone to work on. This information was never enough and even after adding a bounty, you didn't add enough details to seek attention of other members. Add more details and hope someone can crack this for you